# An Error about supervisor

Tags: python, supervisord

OS:macOS Sierra10.12.3

I installed supervisor by 'brew install supervisor' and tried to use it to manage my python program:

```
import get_weibo
import time

while(True):

    get_weibo.get_all()
    time.sleep(60*60*6)
```

`get_weibo` works in console. It's not the problem

and the configuration of supervisor is here

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/usr/local/var/log/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10           ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info                ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/usr/local/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false               ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                  ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                 ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)
umask=022                   ; (process file creation umask;default 022)
user=root ; (default is current user, required if root)
identifier=supervisor       ; (supervisord identifier, default is 'supervisor')
directory=/tmp              ; (default is not to cd during start)
nocleanup=true              ; (don't clean up tempfiles at start;default false)
childlogdir=/tmp            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)
environment=KEY="value"     ; (key value pairs to add to environment)
strip_ansi=false            ; (strip ansi escape codes in logs; def. false)



[program:weibopics]
command=python /Users/HirosueRyouko/PycharmProjects/Supervisor_Py/keep_weibo_pics.py              ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
process_name=%(program_name)s ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
numprocs=1                    ; number of processes copies to start (def 1) directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
umask=022                     ; umask for process (default None)
priority=600                  ; the relative start priority (default 999)
autostart=true                ; start at supervisord start (default: true)
startsecs=1                   ; # of secs prog must stay up to be running (def. 1)
startretries=3                ; max # of serial start failures when starting (default 3)
autorestart=true           ; when to restart if exited after running (def: unexpected)
exitcodes=2                   ; 'expected' exit codes used with autorestart (default 0,2)
stopsignal=QUIT               ; signal used to kill process (default TERM)
stopwaitsecs=10               ; max num secs to wait b4 SIGKILL (default 10)
stopasgroup=false             ; send stop signal to the UNIX process group (default false)
killasgroup=false             ; SIGKILL the UNIX process group (def false)
user=nobody                     ; setuid to this UNIX account to run the program
redirect_stderr=true          ; redirect proc stderr to stdout (default false)
stdout_logfile=/Users/HirosueRyouko/PycharmProjects/Supervisor_Py/weibo_pics_output.log        ; stdout log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
stdout_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stdout logfile backups (default 10)
stdout_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
stdout_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stdout writes (default false)
stderr_logfile=/Users/HirosueRyouko/PycharmProjects/Supervisor_Py/weibo_pics_error.log          ; stderr log path, NONE for none; default AUTO
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=1MB   ; max # logfile bytes b4 rotation (default 50MB)
stderr_logfile_backups=10     ; # of stderr logfile backups (default 10)
stderr_capture_maxbytes=1MB   ; number of bytes in 'capturemode' (default 0)
stderr_events_enabled=false   ; emit events on stderr writes (default false)
environment=A="1",B="2"       ; process environment additions (def no adds)
serverurl=AUTO                ; override serverurl computation (childutils)
```

Here is the input in command line.

> guangmoliangzideMacBook:~ HirosueRyouko$ supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf

Then i got this in Supervisor Status:
[Supervisor Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0G4fp.jpg)

The tail-f:

```
supervisor: couldn't setuid to 4294967294: Can't drop privilege as nonroot user 
supervisor: child process was not spawned
```

How can I work this out?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `sudo` on your command... Read the error... Can't drop privileges *as non-root user*

Or read here about [running without root](https://serverfault.com/questions/144735/how-can-i-run-supervisord-without-using-root)

Says to modify how the `user=` variable is set. Like comment it out entirely

Comment: Thanks for your help.But the sudo doesn't work.And i tried to use different user= like,root,nobody,the name of my account.
and the output is:
supervisor: couldn't setuid to 0: Can't drop privilege as nonroot user
supervisor: child process was not spawned

Comment: Sorry,I don't know how to get the user setting.Is it about my pc or any software?

Comment: Look at your supervisor configuration file. See the line that starts `user=`? You can try deleting both lines of that completely or  comment them out

Comment: here is the tail-f:
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin